# QPushButton setEnabled(false) does not gray out the button with lambda

Tags: c++, lambda, signals-slots, qpushbutton, qt5.5

I discovered a very curious thing. 
I have a big MainWindow class that does a lot of computations with a GUI. In order to keep the GUI responsive, I created a thread for a QTimer that updates the GUI every *n* milliseconds and another thread for the computations, and now all is very smooth and fast.

A simple problem I noticed is that when calling this

```
connect (_worker, &RRTWorker::finished, [=]()
{
    ui->stopButton->setEnabled(false);
});
```

, that is, when the `worker` emits the signal `finished` (when it has ended computations), both with `[=]` and `[&]` the `stopButton` gets disabled **BUT** the label inside is still black (not with that greyish filter as normal disabled buttons).
If you need some feedback, here is a picture:
[image: Bad disabled Stop button]

As you can clearly see, the Start button gets grayed out completely, and that is done in the `on_startButtonclicked()` via the statement
`ui->startButton->setEnabled(false)`.
So, is this a bug, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Are you sure you are not having a custom stylesheet set for the stop button which prevents the color change? Have you tried disabling the button with a non-lambda funtion?

Comment: @DevCybran: Yes, from a non-lambda function all works normally. I just wondered why from a lambda-function this strange event would occur.